# merging structurally-similar methods to avoid repetition

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

**How would I combine / merge / shorten these methods in a more functional style in order to avoid repetition?**

```
public Task<List<UsageSummaryModel>> GetBilledUsageSummary(int accountId, string billingRunId)
        {
            var url = string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}/usage", BaseUrl, accountId, billingRunId);
            return GetAsyncHandlerForRestApi<List<UsageSummaryModel>>(url);
        }

        public Task<GetSampleInvoiceRunIdResponse> GetUnBilledUsageSampleRunId(int accountId)
        {
            var url = string.Format("{0}{1}/sample?usageonly=true", BaseUrl, accountId);
            return GetAsyncHandlerForRestApi<GetSampleInvoiceRunIdResponse>(url);
        }

        public Task<List<UsageSummaryModel>> GetUnBilledUsageSummary(int accountId, int sampleRunId)
        {
            var url = string.Format("{0}{1}/sample/{2}/usage", BaseUrl, accountId, sampleRunId);
            return GetAsyncHandlerForRestApi<List<UsageSummaryModel>>(url);
        }


        public Task<List<CallDetailsRecordModel>> GetBilledCallDetailRecords(int accountId, int billingRunId, int cdrSummaryId, int page, int pageSize)
        {
            var url = string.Empty;

            if (page == -1 && pageSize == -1)//load all records
            {
                url = string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}/usage/{3}", BaseUrl, accountId, billingRunId, cdrSummaryId);
            }
            else
            {
                url = string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}/usage/{3}?page={4}&pageSize={5}", BaseUrl, accountId, billingRunId, cdrSummaryId, page, pageSize);
            }

            return GetAsyncHandlerForRestApi<List<CallDetailsRecordModel>>(url);
        }

        public Task<List<CallDetailsRecordModel>> GetUnBilledCallDetailRecords(int accountId, int sampleRunId, int cdrSummaryId, int page, int pageSize)
        {
            var url = string.Empty;

            if (page == -1 && pageSize == -1)//load all records
            {
                url = string.Format("{0}/{1}/SAMPLE/{2}/usage/{3}", BaseUrl, accountId, sampleRunId, cdrSummaryId);
            }
            else
            {
                url = string.Format("{0}/{1}/SAMPLE/{2}/usage/{3}?page={4}&pageSize={5}", BaseUrl, accountId, sampleRunId, cdrSummaryId, page, pageSize);
            }

            return GetAsyncHandlerForRestApi<List<CallDetailsRecordModel>>(url);
        }
```

Comment: Is there a reason for `int billingRunId` vs `string billingRunId`?

Comment: yes, but for the purposes of simplicity, let's keep them either one or the other data type

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to code review stackexchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and overloaded method that takes a generic type, a url format and a param array of objects as an argument:

```
public static Task<T> GetAsyncHandler(string urlFormat, params object[] args)
{
    string url = string.Format(urlFormat, args);
    return Task<T>.Run( () => { return GetAsyncHandlerForRestApi(url)});
}
```

This allows you to use a single overloaded method to generate your handler.

For example, you can define define it the GetAsyncHandlerForRestApi method in a class `AsyncHandler<T>`:

```
public class AsyncHandler<T>
{
    private string url;

    public AsyncHandler(string url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public static AsyncHandler<T> GetAsyncHandlerForRestApi(string url)
    {
        return new AsyncHandler<T>(url);
    }
    public static Task<T> GetAsyncHandler(string urlFormat, params object[] args)
    {
        string url = string.Format(urlFormat, args);
        return Task<T>.Run( () => { return GetAsyncHandlerForRestApi(url)});
    }
}
```

You can then call the method like this anywhere you would like:

```
 string endPointFormat = BaseUrl + "{0}{1}/sample?usageonly=true";
 Task<List<UsageSummaryModel>> result = AsyncHandler<List<UsageSummaryModel>>.GetAsyncHandler(endPointFormat, accountId);
```

If you still want the separate methods you also define them like this:

```
public Task<List<UsageSummaryModel>> GetBilledUsageSummary(int accountId, string billingRunId)
    {
        string endPointFormat= BaseUrl + "{0}{1}/{2}/usage";
        return AsyncHandler<List<UsageSummaryModel>>.GetAsyncHandler(endPointFormat, accountId, billingRunId);
    }

    public Task<List<UsageSummaryModel>> GetUnBilledUsageSampleRunId(int accountId)
    {
        string endPointFormat = BaseUrl + "{0}{1}/sample?usageonly=true";
        return AsyncHandler<List<UsageSummaryModel>>.GetAsyncHandler(endPointFormat, accountId);
    }
```

As an alternative to using `string urlFormat, params object[] args` as parameters in `GetAsyncHandler` you could define a class to build end points, for example `EndPointBuilder`.

You can use the Factory design pattern to build end point urls for you inside of a method, for example`public string BuildUrl()` and then pass the `EndPointBuilder` to `GetAsyncHandler`

For example:

```
public static Task<T> GetAsyncHandler(EndPointBuilder builder)
{
    string url = BuildUrl.BuildUrl();
    return Task<T>.Run( () => { return GetAsyncHandlerForRestApi(url)});
}
```

You can design EndPointBuilder however you would like to take care of building the urls you need for your service calls.

Comment: very cool! thank you very much. would there be any point to creating this with higher-order functions / closures?

Comment: Sure you could do that if you wanted. For example, you can pass a a function to GetAsyncHandler and have it build the URL for you.